# In my Dart Devtools Timeline view, flutter frame can't zoom smaller

Tags: flutter, dart

I can zoom up flutter frame when scroll up with the mouse wheel.
but  I can't zoom down  when scroll down with the mouse wheel.
Minimum Scale